# React Router V4 protected private route with Redux-persist and React-snapshot

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, persistence, react-router-v4

## I'm implementing private route like so using React Router `Route` Component:

```js
function PrivateRoute({component: Component, authed, emailVerified, ...rest}) {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        authed === true
          ? <Component {...props} />
          : <Redirect to={{pathname: '/', state: {from: props.location}}} />}/>
  )
}
```

### Expected Behavior:

`authed`  is persisted through page refresh through using `redux-persist` 
So on page refresh or reload, if `authed` prop is `true` then router should render `<Component />` without ever going to path `"/"`

### Actual Behavior which is the Problem:

With `authed`  === `true` (persisted) 
reloading the page or refreshing it leads to the following actions taking place(checked `redux devtools`)
the action:
`"@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE"` runs  and takes it to the correct secure route but then `"@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE"` runs again and it redirects to `"/"` for a moment and finally
`"@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE"` runs again and directs route back to the secure path, even though `authed === true` through all this in the `redux devtools`

**Then:**  My guess was that this error has something to with my main `App` Component rendering before `redux-persist` has time to re-hydrate the Redux store.

So I tried doing the following:

I tried delaying my main `App` component render until my store is re-hydrated using `redux-persist` like so:

```js
  render() {
    const {authed, authedId, location, rehydrationComplete} = this.props
    return (
      <div>
      { rehydrationComplete
       ? <MainContainer>
          <Switch key={location.key} location={location}>
            <Route exact={true} path='/' component={HomeContainer} />
            <Route render={() => <h2> Oops. Page not found. </h2>} />
          </Switch>
      </MainContainer>
      : <div>...Loading </div> }
      </div>
    )
  }
```

This effectively fixes the issue above of the path changing when `"@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE"` action runs(only Changes the path keys), **However this leads to another Issue** with `React-snapshot` Now: all the static generated html files from `react-snapshot` Now contain only `...Loading`. I tried to set `snapshotDelay` of `8200` in the `react-snapshot` options but that didnt solve the issue.

**Then:**
I tried the following to delay `React-snapshot` call so that it renders html after the store has been rehydrated:

```js
import {render as snapshotRender} from 'react-snapshot'
import {ConnectedRouter} from 'react-router-redux'

async function init() {
const store = await configureStore()
snapshotRender(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <App />
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)

registerServiceWorker()
}

init()
```

**But now i get the error:** that `'render' from react-snapshot was never called. Did you replace the call to ReactDOM.render()?`

I know this is a loaded question, but I want to effectively use these 3 libs([React-Router V4](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router), [Redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist), [React-snapshot](https://github.com/geelen/react-snapshot)) together to serve protected routes without the mentioned errors.

Comment: Hi @jasan, do you have any shell project we can use as a base? I feel that I'm missing a few pieces there.

Comment: @R.DarioDuarte any update?

Comment: sadly not yet, I attempt to take another approach like using callbacks instead of async await, but get same issue as you. Let you know if I get to something

Comment: @jasan have you tried to use `PersistGate` they [recommend in docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist#usage) ?

Comment: I couldn't solve the issue using react-snapshot but I'm now successfully using react-snap lib which uses puppeteer github.com/stereobooster/react-snap

Comment: @jasan I have a different approach to this problem. Instead of making router with auth aware features, you can make pages aware of auth. Namely, you can specify granularity of auth within a generic container shared across your pages. If you like this i can add more info too..

Answer (score 0):

I have something similar to you. Here I use React-Router V4 and a persist-like library.

Your router/routes doesn't need to be aware of the persist. They should rely on your redux's store. The persist should rehydrate your store with all the data.

I didn't see where you are using the PrivateRoute component in your example. Where is it?